# Python: setting a parameter for a function within a function

Tags: python, function, parameters, args, keyword-argument

I have a function with multiple functions, all of which with 2 required parameters and many optional parameters. I would like to know how to set an optional parameter for a given function within this function:

```
chart_type = "bar"

def chart_selector(slide, df_table, chart_type):

    if chart_type == "bar":
        add_bar_chrt(slide, df_table)
    elif chart_type == "column":
        add_column_chrt(slide, df_table)
    elif chart_type == "pie":
        add_pie_chrt(slide, df_table)
    elif chart_type == "line":
        add_line_chrt(slide, df_table)
```

Here is what I would like to do: I want to use the `chart_selector()` function and if `chart_type` is `"bar"`, then I would like to set a couple of the optional arguments available for the `add_bar_chrt()` function, but I have no idea how?

so I would need to add it to this code somehow:

```
chart = chart_selector(slide, df_table, chart_type)
```

Comment: This is really unclear. Why can't you just put them in your call to add_bar_chrt inside the if statement?

Comment: Just add the additional arguments to the function call, e.g. `add_bar_chrt(slide, df_table, optional_arg1, optional_arg2, anotherarg=123)`

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman, apologies but the topic itself is confusing for me, but I believe I have done what you have suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add arbitrary argument support by using `*args` and `**kwargs` to your function signature, then pass those on:

```
def chart_selector(slide, df_table, chart_type, *args, **kwargs):
    if chart_type == "bar":
        add_bar_chrt(slide, df_table, *args, **kwargs)
```

Any *extra* arguments you now pass to `chart_selector()` are now passed on to `add_bar_chrt()`.

While you are working on this function anyway, consider using a dictionary to dispatch the chart types:

```
chart_types = {
    'bar': add_bar_chrt,
    'column': add_column_chrt,
    'pie': add_pie_chart,
    'line': add_line_chart,
}
def chart_selector(slide, df_table, chart_type, *args, **kwargs):
    return chart_types[chart_type](slide, df_table, *args, **kwargs)
```

The dictionary replaces the many-branched `if`..`elif`.. structure.

Demo:

```
>>> def add_bar_chrt(slide, tbl, size=10, color='pink'):
...     return 'Created a {} barchart, with bars size {}'.format(size, color)
... 
>>> def add_column_chrt(slide, tbl, style='corinthyan', material='marble'):
...     return 'Created a {} column chart, with {}-style plinths'.format(material, style)
... 
>>> chart_types = {
...     'bar': add_bar_chrt,
...     'column': add_column_chrt,
... }
>>> def chart_selector(slide, df_table, chart_type, *args, **kwargs):
...     return chart_types[chart_type](slide, df_table, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> chart_selector('spam', 'eggs', 'bar')
'Created a 10 barchart, with bars size pink'
>>> chart_selector('spam', 'eggs', 'column', material='gold')
'Created a gold column chart, with corinthyan-style plinths'
```

Comment: Using a dict to replace the operators is a great idea. Will try all of this now and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time and effort, it works well! Now I know what *args and **kwargs do and will try to use them in the future.